# printstream fails to prints as what I wish

Tags: java

I open a server socket at localhost's port e.g 11111, and I also include printstream for stream data which i would want to output as neat as expected like this

```
PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(),false);
ps.println("<h1>Hello, it works!</h1>");
```

I am looking forward to seeing the output as **Hello, it works!**
but it becomes like this `<h1>Hello, it works!</h1>`

**Update**
I am not working with serlet or jsp, this simply is a webserver I would like to display a welcome message once the user visit the `http://localhost:111111`

Thank you

Comment: Where you are seeing the output ?

Comment: thanks, I look at it in the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create a simple web server then you need to return a valid HTTP response that contain status code and content-type at the very least:

```
PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream(), false);
ps.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
ps.println("Content-Type: text/html\n");
ps.println("<h1>Hello, it works!</h1>");
```

You can find more details about what HTTP response look like [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)

Comment: The newlines should be \r\n in HTTP, and there should be a blank line between the headers and the body.

Comment: He does have a newline between the header and the body, he is only missing the carriage return.